# How to access a main document class array from a movieclip?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash

I have an array in my main

```
public var graphArray:Array = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
```

And I'm trying to access it from within a MovieClip that I've put on my timeline using:

```
var graph1scale:Number = MovieClip(root).graphArray[0]
```

It looks like it would make sense to me but when I try to run it I get this error:

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

Am I wrong to be using MovieClip(root) to try and access it? I've only just started using external classes (this is my first project doing so) and usually I just do everything on the timeline. So MovieClip(root) is familiar to me but I guess it's not the right thing to do here.

Is there a way I can access vars from Main.as?

**-----SOLVED-----**

I realised MovieClip(root) did work all along but I was just calling on the array before the array was being defined in Main.as. I put a delay on calling graphArray and it worked.

Not sure how that makes sense though because the graphArray is the first thing I've defined in the whole main.as class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this instead

```
MovieClip(this.root)
```

This works for me on a test that you can see here:

http://marksost.com/test/as3arrayaccess/

And the source files here:

http://marksost.com/test/as3arrayaccess/test.zip